# Speed decreases when using OpenMP 4.0 (gcc 4.8.4) instead of OpenMP 3.1 (gcc 4.9.2)

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, openmp

so, I have existing code where several instructions are parallelized by using simply

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, 1 )
[instruction set A with 4 instructions -> 4 threads]

#pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, 1 )
[instruction set B with 4 instructions -> 4 threads]

#pragma omp parallel for schedule( static, 1 )
[instruction set C with 4 instructions -> 4 threads]
```

The code executes on a 4-core i5 machine quite quickly, CPU core usage is 100% for almost all the time.

The threads are scheduled nicely, i.e.:

```
Core 1 handles instruction A1 -> B1 -> C1
Core 2 handles instruction A2 -> B2 -> C2 
Core 3 handles instruction A3 -> B3 -> C3
```

This is -- IMHO -- important since e.g. instruction B1 depends on the data of instruction A1 etc.

However, I have a new machine (with a faster 6-core CPU) where the program executes slower.

My best shot is currently, that the scheduling doesn't work as good in this case.

Since I as well changed the compiler from gcc 4.8.4 to 4.9.2, the implicit OpenMP-change from 3.1 to 4.0 and 4.0's default scheduling settings may be the reason for the scheduling problems (?).

Is there a way to configure OpenMP 4.0 that it schedules just as OpenMP3.1 did?
I found e.g.

```
GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY
OMP_PROC_BIND
OMP_PARTS
...
```

I just didn't find any hint on how to make 4.0 and 3.1 behave similarly...

I can't share my code, since it's way too large and currently, I don't have a minimal example where I can analyze it, sorry.

**update:**
The instructions as such are likely not the cause, since it has worked before. What I can tell you is:

- Each instruction takes ~5ms single-core processing time, so they operate quite fast.
- The instructions (A, B, C) are computed after each other
- Before starting B, the execution waits for all As to finish, etc (before C starts, all Bs have to finish)
- For each instruction, 3 SIMD threads (e.g. A1, A2, A3) are computed in parallel
- each instruction A, B, C depends on data of their predecessors (e.g. B1 uses data from A1, but no data from any "2" or "3" instruction, which *should* run on different cores)

What I want is a core-wise binding such that

```
Core 1 handles instruction A1 -> B1 -> C1
Core 2 handles instruction A2 -> B2 -> C2 
Core 3 handles instruction A3 -> B3 -> C3
```

Comment: I am sorry but can you please specify which instructions that you are compiling? The example is I think too generic.

Comment: I added some more information about the instructions, hope it helps

Comment: Presence or absence of OpenMP 4 support shouldn't affect the performance of OpenMP 3.1 constructs.  Setting affinity does become more important as you increase the number of cores, particularly if you have hyperthreads enabled.  If you require barriers due to sequential dependency between parallel regions, it might not be surprising that increasing number of cores is not entirely effective.

Comment: The additional cores aren't so much my focus -- the newer CPU has more cache, each single core has a higher frequency, yet it doen't run faster (it's even slower)

Comment: I agree with @tim18. There are multiple factors here: compiler version, hardware, ... Have you considered on building a static binary on the "old" system and give it a try on the new system?

Comment: In order for the community to help you, consider putting your whole code. There could be any number of factors  as @Harald mentioned. For instance, you have a new machine, that means now you have a different operating system, different programs running in the background. Also, what data input size are you using? Try different data sizes, going until very, very large.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of debugging and trying to identify the problem, I was able to fix it:

It was *not* an issue with OpenMP, but with the hardware. The OS apparently reduced the CPU frequency (from 3900MHz to 1200MHz) even **while** the process was running. When I disabled all CPU power saving settings in the BIOS, the process was running with the expected speed. FYI: Intel i7-5930K, ASUS X99-E WS.